Difference between "take the bull by the horns" and "bite the bullet"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'take the bull by the horns' and 'bite the bullet'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

take the bull by the horns: to do something difficult in a brave and determined way
bite the bullet: to force yourself to do something unpleasant or difficult, or to be brave in a difficult situation


Note, despite the similarity, "bull" and "bullet" are not related in their etymology.

These definitions you found are not especially good IMHO. They're a little short on detail. It might be better to look up other sources than just rely on one.
Although these idioms are similar, there is a difference in nuance.
To take the bull by the horns is to take a difficult task/situation in hand, to decisively take control of it. To deal with something that is literally dangerous/wayward (like a bull with horns). To face a problem head-on, and just get the job done.
To bite the bullet is similar in the sense of dealing with a difficult task/situation, but also implies that one should accept or submit to the inevitable pain/unpleasantness/suffering experienced when doing something difficult by being brave in the face of adversity, stoical, showing no fear, and not complaining, etc.
The OED has a wonderful attestation for chewing a bullet, which could be describing the source of this idiom. It would also seem to explain the nuance.

1788
"It is a point of honour in some regiments..never to cry out..whilst
under the discipline of the cat of nine tails; to avoid which, they
chew a bullet."
F. Grose, Classical Dictionary of Vulgar Tongue (ed. 2) at Nightingale


+1 You can "bite the bullet" and have that sensitive tooth seen to by the dentist but you wouldn't be "taking the bull by the horns" when doing so.   The dentist might say to stop biting bullets.

OP's query is on the difference between the two idioms:

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'take the bull by the horns' and 'bite the bullet'?

The Cambridge dictionary's example sentences will help in clarifying how the two idioms are used differently:
1. Take the bull by the horns:  to deal with a difficult situation in a very direct way

(e.g., "I took the bull by the horns and confronted him about his mistreatment of the workers.")

2. Bite the bullet:  to force yourself to do something unpleasant or difficult, or to be brave in a difficult situation.

(e.g., "I hate going to the dentist, but I'll just have to bite the bullet.")

In summary, the key differences between these idioms are:

Take the bull by the horns: (proactive or taking action) Face challenges with courage and bold action.
Bite the bullet: (inevitable circumstances) Endure necessary or unavoidable circumstances..


What is the source?

@Mari-LouA The example sentences are given with the meaning OP has quoted. (Cambridge dictionary)

You need to distinguish between the different levels of meaning.  At the surface level, these are obviously very different (one is about an animal, another is about a projectile).
But the proverbial meaning is very similar. They are used to give the same advice:  do something difficult now, and don't procrastinate. It is not unusual for two or more proverbs to have the same proverbial meaning.  You could use either proverb.
Perhaps there is a small difference, because "bite the bullet" is a small single act, but "take the bull by the horns" is a longer action.  So to tell some to do one thing "bite the bullet" but to tell a person to do a complex task "take the bull".  It's not a big or significant difference, and it's not something that you can get "wrong".
Both expressions are clichés.  They are tired and over-used expressions.  Good authors will try to avoid clichés if possible.

I would dispute that bite the bullet is 'a small single act'.  It is alleged to derive from soldiers being given a soft lead bullet to bite down on during painful surgery, so it's about resolving to submit yourself to an experience you know will be unpleasant.

@KateBunting - I would agree and say that biting the bullet may be more about deciding to submit to something and taking the bull by the horns is more about doing something yourself. I bit the bullet and agreed to let my father-in-law come over, and when he was there I took the bull by the horns and asked him about his prison sentence.
